# Sketch of $(y^2-1)\sin\big(\cosh(x^3y)\big)=x^2-4$

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

So I'm in enriched math and teacher asks us to draw the graph(sketch) of

$$(y^2-1)\sin\big(\cosh(x^3y)\big)=x^2-4$$

How to do it? :S

Comment: That is one weird "function "
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28y%5E2-1%29*sin%28cosh%28x%5E3*y%29%29%3Dx%5E2-1%3B

Comment: Man, that thing is scary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Are you **positive** your teacher wasn't joking?

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien Sometimes, the ugliness of this world needs to be revealed.

Comment: I actually find it pretty. Well, some sort of disturbed pretty...

Comment: Based on this I'd guess the teacher wanted the students to use software to graph it, not work it out by hand. Maybe to prove a point, like "implicit functions can be complicated".